# Scala ClosedByInterruptException using os.lib watch service

Tags: scala

One new to scala here!
Im trying to use os.lib.watch to read json files when there is file name change happening in the directory. Problem is that i cannot get the json file read when i change the filename manually to something else.

```
object Main extends App {
//this works no problem
  val jsonPath = os.Path("/users/tst.json")
  val jsonString = os.read(jsonPath)
  val data = ujson.read(jsonString)
  println(data)

  def readFileContent(file: os.Path){
  println("Reading Input Json..")
  val jsonString = os.read(file) //fail
  val data = ujson.read(jsonString)
  println(data)
  }

  def processFile(filePath: os.Path) {
    println("FileName:"+ filePath)
    readFileContent(filePath)
  }

  os.watch.watch(Seq(os.pwd/"output"),
  f => processFile(f.last))
}
```

sbt:

```
"com.lihaoyi" %% "os-lib" % "0.7.8",  "com.lihaoyi" %% "os-lib-watch" % "0.4.2"
```

Error when reading the json file:

```
JNA: Callback os.watch.FSEventsWatcher$$anon$1@82009c threw the following exception:
java.nio.channels.ClosedByInterruptException
    at java.nio.channels.spi.AbstractInterruptibleChannel.end(AbstractInterruptibleChannel.java:202)
    at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.read(FileChannelImpl.java:164)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:65)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:109)
    at sun.nio.ch.ChannelInputStream.read(ChannelInputStream.java:103)
    at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
    at os.Internals$.transfer0(Internals.scala:15)
    at os.Internals$.transfer(Internals.scala:23)
    at os.read$bytes$.apply(ReadWriteOps.scala:257)
    at os.read$.apply(ReadWriteOps.scala:216)
    at os.read$.apply(ReadWriteOps.scala:214)
    at Main$.readFileContent(Main.scala:21)
    at Main$.processFile(Main.scala:28)
    at Main$.$anonfun$new$1(Main.scala:33)
    at Main$.$anonfun$new$1$adapted(Main.scala:33)
    at os.watch.FSEventsWatcher$$anon$1.invoke(FSEventsWatcher.scala:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.invokeCallback(CallbackReference.java:520)
    at com.sun.jna.CallbackReference$DefaultCallbackProxy.callback(CallbackReference.java:551)
    at com.sun.jna.Native.invokeVoid(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:414)
    at com.sun.jna.Function.invoke(Function.java:360)
    at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.invoke(Library.java:244)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy3.CFRunLoopRun(Unknown Source)
    at os.watch.FSEventsWatcher.run(FSEventsWatcher.scala:75)
    at os.watch.package$.$anonfun$watch$1(package.scala:39)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```